# Django form data isn't saving to database

Tags: django, django-forms

i'm trying to allow a user to update their user profile with a city, description, website address etc.

Using Django 2.0, I have two forms in one view:

EditProfileForm (EPF) = Form for email, first and last name and password

The EditProfileForm seems to be able to save data. However, EditUserProfile seems to not.

EditUserProfile (EUP) = Form for further user info such as city, description, website address etc.

When entering the data and submitting the form, the data for EUP form doesn't appear to save or update the user information

I've also tried methods such as:

```
if form_EUP.is_valid():
    obj = form_EUP.save(commit=False)
    obj.user = request.user
    obj.save()
```

and trying to create a similar custom save method to the format used in RegistrationForm but i've had no luck

I'm a bit of a beginner to the django framework so any ideas would be much appreciated, cheers.

## views.py

```
def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_EPF = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        form_EUP = EditUserProfile(request.POST, instance=request.user)

        if form_EPF.is_valid():
            form_EPF.save()
            return redirect(reverse('accounts:view_profile'))

        if form_EUP.is_valid():
            form_EUP.save()
            return redirect(reverse('accounts:view_profile'))

    else:
        form_EPF = EditProfileForm(instance=request.user)
        form_EUP = EditUserProfile(instance=request.user)

        args = {'form_EPF': form_EPF, "form_EUP": form_EUP}
        return render(request, 'accounts/edit_profile.html', args)
```

## forms.py

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'username', 
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'password1',
            'password2'
            )

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user

class EditProfileForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'email',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'password',
            )

class EditUserProfile(ModelForm):
    description = forms.CharField(required=False)
    city = forms.CharField(required=False)
    website = forms.URLField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = (
            'description',
            'city',
            'website',
            'image',
            )
```

## models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    website = models.URLField(default='')
    phone = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])

post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

## edit_profile.html

```
{% block body %}
<div class="container">
    <h1>Edit profile</h1>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form_EPF.as_p }}
        {{ form_EUP.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
    if form_EPF.is_valid():
        form_EPF.save()
        return redirect(reverse('accounts:view_profile')) # !!!!!

    if form_EUP.is_valid():
        form_EUP.save()
        return redirect(reverse('accounts:view_profile'))
```

You are returning just after saving the user form, so the profile form is indeed never saved (unless the user form is invalid xD).

You want:

```
    if form_EPF.is_valid() and form_EUP.is_valid():
        form_EPF.save()
        form_EUP.save()
        return redirect(reverse('accounts:view_profile')) # !!!!!
```

Also, you have this which won't work:

```
form_EUP = EditUserProfile(request.POST, instance=request.user)
```

you're passing a ̀User`as`instance`, but the form expects a`UserProfile`.

And - while it won't prevent your code from running - you definitly want to think twice about your naming. "EditProfileForm" edits the User so it should really be named "EditUserForm" (or "UserEditForm" etc), and the variables in your view aren't any better - ̀form_EPF`and`form_EUP`requires active thinking to parse the suffix and match it with the (already counter-intuitive) form class names, and you _don't_ want to have to do any effort to understand what a name means when reading code. Just use the all_lower form of the class instead, so assumin you renamed your form classes to a much saner`UserEditForm`and`ProfileEditForm`, the variables would be`user_edit_form`and`profile_edit_form`. That's a couple additional keystrokes indeed but on average you spend about 1000 times more time reading code than writing it so it's really worth optimizing for reading.

Comment: Cheers man, very much appreciated! Very good points about the variable names so I’ll sort them out. Thanks again!